# Use freed memory could really crash ?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

The following code access to memory that is no more allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int * ptr = new int(5);
        delete ptr;
        return *ptr;
}
```

The pointer access to memory that is no more allocated but till the memory is accessible it will just return a value.
I wonder if, practically, it is possible that the program ends crashing with a segmentation violation signal.

EDIT: I run in a loop the program more than 100000 times without crash, that does not means it will never crash, just that it has not crashed during theses 100000 times. Perhaps it is not possible with a so simple program ?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Undefined Behavior! The compiler is now free to emit nasal demons.

Comment: @user------- It's really different, the purpose here is to know wheter an undefined behaviour could crash the program.

Comment: Oh, so this means if *the single step* between `delete` and `return` can lead to a crash? Yes, that is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case that crash with a segmentation violation (based on the example of Thomas) could be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        size_t size = 1024*1024;
        char *ptr = new char[size];
        memset(ptr,255,size);
        delete [] ptr;
        return ptr[0];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I wonder if it is possible that this makes crash the program with a segmentation violation signal or such kind of thing.

Yes. De-referencing a deleted pointer is *undefined behaviour*. One of the things could happen is a crash. Another is that the program could silently exit without any problems.

Comment: Where the second ('silently exit') is worse than a segfault - it hides the problem

Comment: is there a way by which we can force gcc to crash the program if code is found(by gcc) to be UB?

Comment: @Koushik UB is UB.  You cannot force it to do anything - if it orders you a pizza, that is valid behavior.  That is why you avoid writing code that has UB.

Comment: @ZacHowland i'm perfectly fine with pizza :-) , but compilers can find UB code and hence i'm asking if i can force(through a command-line switch) to crash the program in case i find something not conforming. this might be the case if i use external library. so asked. there are diagnostics emitted i know but still curious.

Comment: @Koushik: No.  For one thing, not all "undefined behavior" is *bad*; it just means that the language standard doesn't require the compiler to behave in a particular way.  For another, crashing is a *runtime* issue; gcc has no control over the program once it's built and running.

Comment: @Koushik If any such ability existed, it would be implementation dependent.  Thus, it may work on g++ (for example), but have no corresponding feature for VS (or vice versa).  The standard specifies UB, which is why you avoid coding it.  It is the programmer's responsibility to write good code, not the compiler's.

Comment: @Koushik: Compilers can, in principle, find *some* UB (including this example); but some can only be detected at run-time, if at all. A slight modification to this, storing the dangling pointer and then accessing it later, couldn't be detected by static analysis.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes i think "find **some** UB" answers my question. my question was also limited to this question where compiler knows about the pointer. thanks

Comment: @juanchopanza : I know could bring unpredicatable behaviour, but if there is only an access did you have already seen a crash in such situation ?

Comment: @mpromonet I tend not to to write code with undefined behaviour. I might try your sample and see. But I don't know what there is to learn from such an experiment.

Comment: @juanchopanza : the real code is in a COTS that I cannot modify, I would like to know if a read access to a freed memory could crash the program that use this COTS.

Comment: @mpromonet Yes, it *could* crash the program, unless your platform specifically guarantees that it doesn't.

Comment: @juanchopanza I guess you right, however I run the program thousand of times without crash. I also tried different compilation option. It is also possible that to see a crash it is need to make a bigger alloc/free ?

Answer (score 3):

ptr still contains a memory address. Whether or not accessing this particular address in the context of your process depends on the state of the operating system's memory management and whether the heap management of your system's C++ compiler might return memory freed due to delete to the OS memory management. If it's gone, you'll see a segment violation.

But chances are that accessing the address is still possible and your program won't be terminated due to trespassing. But even if this is certain, you won't have any guarantee that the value returned from main is still the value the variable held before the delete. Heap memory management is a very intricate piece of software and there's no telling what happens to the chunk of memory while it is returned.

Finally, if your program uses threads, another thread may have requested memory and received and changed what was returned a few nanoseconds ago.

So: don't, never, ever!

Comment: The code is such an exemple, the real situation is inside a COTS that have such a problem. In the real code an other condition prevent to make bad thing but it access to deleted memory. Did you have an example with read access to deleted memory that ends with a segmentation violation ?

Comment: @mpromonet If the memory allocation is large, the decommit is more likely. Try a few megabytes. Also, turning on the debug heap (application verifier in page heap mode on Windows) will trigger the access violation even for small heap blocks.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it *could* really crash ;)

Your example is actually too simple to crash though. For your example to crash, your process (the standard C library) would have to return the memory to the Operating System in the `delete` command. Since the memory on most systems today is [organized in pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), you would have to allocate memory big enough so that when its freed, the whole page is freed and returned to the OS. The segmentation fault occurs when you access memory that is not mapped - this is the case of the memory that was returned to the OS. But, you are allocating *too small* amount of memory for that to happen.

If you want a crash, give the system more chance :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// number of megabytes you will allocate
#define N 100
 
int main()
{
        char *ptr[N];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                ptr[i] = new char[1*1024*1024];
        }
        // if you remove the following loop, it won't crash
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                delete ptr[i];
        }
        return ptr[0][2000];
}
```

This crashes every time on my system. Even in your case it could crash if your `int` would be just the last thing on that page (well not surely, depends on the implementation of the standard C library), but a lot of chance would be needed for that, and its implementation dependent.

**I just created more likely crash-case for you to actually *believe* it could happen :-)**

Comment: a little complex, but your example show that it could happen  allocating a big memory block (with 1kB it does not crash and it crash with 1MB).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should **never** work on freed memory.

The use of heap allocated memory after it has been freed or deleted leads to **undefined system behavior**.

Sometimes it could **appears to work**, sometimes it does not work, depending if your freed memory is reused.

Comment: Where the "sometimes it could work" is actually, it will never "work", but may **appear** to work simply because the memory hasn't been reallocated yet.

Comment: I am agree with you ;) Ahah, but I already encountered some case, this problem cause crash 1/2, and works fine 1/2.

Comment: You mean it *appears* to work in the other half.  As it is UB, it can never be stated to "work".

Answer (score -1):

The C standard only says that deferencing a freed pointer is undefined behaviour. It does not say it **has to** crash. It says nothing about what should happen really.

You would have to understand what "delete" actually does. Probably memory is just lazyly deleted by the operating system, and marked as free for available use, but since no other process has taken ownership of this memory between the 'delete ptr' and the 'return ptr', it does not surprise me that you do not segfault here.

But again, your question cannot be answered anymore than by saying it's undefined behaviour. What the baheviour is can depend on the implementation and the operating system, and be random and unpredictable (such as dependant on another process having had time to appropriate this memory between the delete and the return).

Comment: What you explain is in the question, it's clear that this should not be done, but bugs are in lots of pieces of software, and sometimes in pieces you cannot modify !